# Such a huge mass for Higgs boson? And how can it, as a quantum, decay?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, higgs

With a mass of 126GeV/c<sup>2</sup> Higgs boson would have a mass slightly greater than a caesium atom. Isn't it too much? Wouldn't be in this way the ubiquitous Higgs field so dense to cause problems for the existence of vacuum? Furthermore, since this boson is a quantum of the Higgs field, how can a quantum (which should be indivisible) decay in lighter particles such as a fermion-antifermion pair?

Comment: You are confusing the Higgs field with the Higgs boson.  The Higgs boson is an excitation of the Higgs field, in the same way that the electron is an excitation of the electron field. It is the Higgs field that with its non zero vacuum expectation value generates the masses.  That value btw is about twice the value of the mass of the excitation.  Not the 126GeV/c^2 boson.

Comment: Higgs boson is the quantum excitation of the Higgs field. Clear. It is an elementary scalar particle. So, how can it decay if it is elementary? And the mass given for it is 126GeV, a bit more than caesium... a lot! So, if Higgs field is ubiquitous and Higgs bosons are its (so massive) excitations, I think this field would be very cumbersome and vacuum couldn't exist.

Comment: Guess what. It does decay, it is an experimental fact that it does, as also the W and the Z which also are in the elementary particle table.  including the top

Answer (score 2):

The vacuum is defined as the state where the Higgs field (and the rest of quantum fields) have no excitations. The mass of the Higgs boson is the minimum energy that you have to supply to the Higgs field in order to create an excitation. The huge mass for the Higgs field means that it is more difficult to create excitations, so there is no problem to the existence of the vacuum. [By the way, the *stability* of that vacuum is another question, because the potential of the Higgs becomes unstable at large energies]. The Higgs boson isn't the heaviest elementary particle, the top quark has 173 GeV/c<sup>2</sup>, like an atom of gold.

In the quantum realm, *stable* and *elementary* particles are quite different concepts. A particle is said to be *elementary* if it is structureless, that is, if it behaves like a point-particle in scattering experiments (from a more theoretical point of view, elementary fields are the degrees of freedom of the most fundamental lagrangian). Any particle, elementary or not, has some probability to decay to others when allowed by the conservation laws. As Gell-Mann [once said](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totalitarian_principle), "Everything not forbidden is compulsory".

A 125 GeV/c<sup>2</sup> indeed decays, and very quickly: its mean lifetime is around 10<sup>-22</sup> s. It decays to fermion-antifermion pairs (the principal decay channel is bottom-antibottom quarks), and also to weak bosons and, through more complicated processes, to gluons and photons.

[image: Higgs Branching Ratios]

In this plot you can see the branching ratios (the probability for each final state after the decay) as a function of the Higgs mass. Source: H. E. Habber: *Viewpoint: Homing in on the Higgs Boson*. Physics 5, 32 (2012) [Link](https://physics.aps.org/articles/v5/32)